# Tp-link Tl-wn8200nd-v2 as an access point

Tags: wireless, 18.04, wireless-access-point, tp-link

Have anyone use the "Tp-link Tl-wn8200nd" v2 as an access point? And how is it done (and which controller is used)?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: What is 'Tp-link Tl-wn8200nd'?

Comment: It is a usb adapter: https://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4734_TL-WN8200ND.html